# C# - Read attribut value in method updated

Tags: c#, methods, attributes

I have a custom Attribute named

```
[Usermustwait(UserHaveToWait = 0, UserMustWait = false)]
```

In this attribute, the method update both variable, i want to get these value and not the value i define ...
I tried the exemple bellow, but he return 0 and false ...

```
GetType().GetMethod(currentMethodName).GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<Usermustwait>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Hope you could help me
Thanks

---

The attribut class :

```
public class UserMustWait : PreconditionAttribute
{

    public bool UserMustWait { get; set; } = false;
    public int UserHaveToWait { get; set; } = 0;

    public UserMustWait()
    {
    }

    public override Task<PreconditionResult> CheckPermissionsAsync(ICommandContext context, CommandInfo command, IServiceProvider services)
    {
        // doing some stuff to verify in a SQLDatabase if the user catched in the context have a specified role or not
        // if have not a specified role : 
        // UserMustWait = true;
        // UserHaveToWait = XX;
        // I need to read these value in my method to be sure the user wait the number in milisecond
        
        return Task.FromResult(PreconditionResult.FromSuccess());
    }

}
```

The method :

```
    [Usermustwait(UserHaveToWait = 0, UserMustWait = false)]
    public async Task join(string arg)
    {
        // this is where i need to read the value updated by the attribut 
        // if(UserMustWait = true) 
        //      SendMessage("You have to wait {UserHaveToWait} secondes");
        // 
    }
```

Comment: I think you want to use reflection to inspect an instance of an object rather than the type definition 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/accessing-attributes-by-using-reflection

Comment: How to use reflection in a method ? 
My attrbute is define on method not a class

Comment: @wdomains You cannot set an attribute for an object instance.

Comment: @maxime did you use this attribute on a method? Can you show your usage?

Comment: @jason thanks for answer, see in the first post the edit to show

Comment: You cannot change the values within an attribute at runtime, whenever you get an attribute via `GetCustomAttribute` a new instance is created with the values from the annotation. If you want to track variable state you can use fields on the class, perhaps you want to set defaults via an attribute but it is a little hard to see their use in this scenario.

Comment: I edited the post with comments to explain the best i could what i want